# Imploding an array issue in php

Tags: php

I have this code above which i use to implode some variable. 
The issue is that i need to create the same thing for `$hostess_name[]` as i did for  `$hostess_id_selected[]`.
I don't know what am i doing wrong.
I need to implode it the same way as i did with `$hostess_id_selected1`

```
 foreach($hostess_id as $val) {
   $hostess_id_selected[] = $val;
   $sqlnomehostess="SELECT nome_hostess FROM hostess where id='$val'";
   $resultnomehostess=mysql_query($sqlnomehostess)or die(mysql_error());
   $hostess_name= array();

   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultnomehostess,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     $hostess_name[] = $row['nome_hostess'];
   }
 }

 $hostess_id_selected1 = implode("-",$hostess_id_selected);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have $hostess_name= array(); inside the loop. move it above

**EDIT:**

some tips:

```
 foreach($hostess_id as $val) {
   $hostess_id_selected[] = $val;
 // this is pointless, i mean - you are recreating $hostess_id
```

btw, just a little tip for improvement - instead of running many SQL queries you can use a single query:

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONTACT(`nome_hostess` SEPARATOR '-') AS name_list 
        FROM `hostess` 
        WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$hostess_id).")";
```

if the items in $hostess_id are not necessarily numeric:

```
$sql_ids = array();
foreach($hostess_id as $id)
    $sql_ids[] = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONTACT(`nome_hostess` SEPARATOR '-') AS name_list 
        FROM `hostess` 
        WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$sql_ids).")";
```

and after that:

the sql query returns 1 row with a column called "name_list", which contains the names joined with "-".

if you want to maintain the order of the id and name - you should do:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
             GROUP_CONTACT(`nome_hostess` SEPARATOR '-') AS name_list,
             GROUP_CONTACT(`id` SEPARATOR '-') AS id_list 
        FROM `hostess` 
        WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$hostess_id).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

implode is a basic function of php. It always work perfect.
Just check your array $hostess_id_selected, what it returning.
I think it will help you.